# Factoring the Negative outside of Parentheses Squared

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Dealing with the four step process of finding a derivative. I haven't been in math for a year and a half, so I've forgotten a lot of basic rules.

So basically,  if the function is $f(x)=-x^2+3x$, then the first step would be $f(x+h)$.

So then you have $-(x+h)^2+3(x+h)$.

What I don't know is how to factor $-(x+h)^2$.

I'd assume it'd be $-(x+h) \times -(x+h).$ If so, do I distribute the negative $(-x-h) \times (-x-h)$ and keep them in parenthesis since I have to multiply them? Or does the negative not matter and they would still be $(x^2 + 2xh + h^2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You square first, and then apply the negative, since the negative is outside the parentheses.

So,

$$-(x+h)^2 = -(x^2 + 2xh + h^2) = -x^2 - 2xh - x^2.$$

If the negative were *inside*, it would be different:

$$[-(x+h)]^2 = [(-1)(x+h)]^2 = (-1)^2(x+h)^2 = (x+h)^2 = x^2 - 2xh+ h^2.$$

Getting back to the initial problem, $f(x)=-x^2 + 3x$, order of operations applies.  The negative sign is the same as multiplication by $-1$.  In the absence of parentheses, exponents are handled before multiplication and division, which in turn are handled before addition and subtraction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got stuck on step 2 and couldn't eliminate anything, so you've helped me out a lot.

Comment: Glad to help!  Also, see what I added afterwards.  It explains why $-x^2$ is interpreted as $-(x)^2$ rather than $(-x)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$-(x+h)^2\not =\{-(x+h)\}\times\{-(x+h)\}.$$We have$$-(x+h)^2=-(x+h)(x+h)=-(x^2+xh+hx+h^2)$$$$=-(x^2+2xh+h^2)=-x^2-2xh-h^2.$$